# Scratch the screen to display an image in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

i am working on a android project for my assignment. i am trying to make a scratch image application, you know it's like we scratch the screen to get rid the blocking layer to display the image. but the problem is i don't know where to start.

i have searching in stackoverflow's questions that related to this but that's not help.
from my search there, i found a clue for this project is using `Bitmap.getPixel(int x, int y)`.

so, in my thought i have to get pixel from bitmap and paint it to canvas.
but i don't know how to implement it?
or anyone has a better method for this?

Could anyone please help me? Any tutorials on this kind of thing or related topics?

Thanks in advance!

---

here's my sample code:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    tw = w;
    th = h;
    eraseableBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(eraseableBitmap);
    Bitmap muteableBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(eraseableBitmap.getWidth(), eraseableBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    static_x = event.getX();
    static_y = event.getY();

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        touch_start(static_x, static_y);

    } if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            touch_move(static_x, static_y);

    } if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            touch_up(); 
        }
    return true;
}
```

---

Here's the appearance of my project:

[image: layout]

Comment: what do you mean scratch the screen? Like a scratch off lotto ticket?

Comment: @Tim ya, like that! do you any idea how to make something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting question. My theoretical plan:

You have 2 bitmaps, the 'erasable' bitmap and the 'hidden' bitmap. Erasing pixels from an existing bitmap is not possible because Bitmap's in Android are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So instead of erasing pixels from the 'erasable' bitmap to reveal the bitmap underneath, first draw the 'erasable' bitmap. Then create an empty, [mutable Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29). Loop over all of the pixels in the 'hidden' bitmap, displaying only where the 'erasable' bitmap has been 'erased'.

```
Bitmap mutableBitmap = Bitmap.create(erasableBitmap.getWidth(),erasableBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

for(Pixel erasedPixel : erasedList)
{
  mutableBitmap.setPixel(x,y, hiddenBitmap.getPixel(erasedPixel.x, erasedPixel.y));
}

...
// in a different file
class Pixel{
  int x, y;

}
```

you'll have to fill the erasedList yourself.

Once you are done, draw to the canvas like so:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(0,0,eraseableBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(0,0,mutableBitmap);
```

making sure that you draw the 'erasable' bitmap first so that it is drawn over with the new pixels.

If you need help figuring out how to set the erased pixels, let me know in the comments and I'll help you out.

EDIT

To actually figure out which pixels the user tried to erase: In your view, capture the onTouch event and you'll get a coordinate of where the user touched the screen. <strike>Save that to a some sort of map or hashtable and you should be good to go.</strike> Create a Pixel object and add it to a global `List` of pixels.

EDIT 2

To increase the size of the "scratch" what you have to do is a little complicated. You need some way to create an area around the x,y point touched to also count as erased. A circle would be ideal but it will be easier to use a square.

```
for(Pixel erasedPixel: erasedList)
{
  //it's actually more complicated than this, since you need to check for boundary conditions.
  for(int i = -SQUARE_WIDTH/2; i < SQUARE_WIDTH/2; i++){
    for(int j = -SQUARE_WIDTH/2; j < SQUARE_WIDTH/2; j++){
      mutableBitmap.setPixel(erasedPixel.x+i, erasedPixel.y+j, hiddenBitmap.getPixel(erasedPixel.x+i, erasedPixel.y+j));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i think your idea is the best way to make this happen. as like what you said above, i need help to figure it out. sorry if i asked to much, i am beginning android programmer.

Comment: can i ask you one more time? i have done what you said above, and when i scratch the erasableBitmap, mutableBitmap is revealed, but it takes a day to scratch all the image coz it only reveal per pixel. do you have an idea how to reveal it per round/square not per pixel? thanks you, sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: but if i have to use circle instead of square, how i do it? sorry if ask you again. i don't know how to make it. thank you again and i am so sorry to ask you again.

Comment: I think I've done more than enough to answer your questions. I don't want to write your whole program for you. Google the phrase "filling a circle's pixels" and you should be able to find more information. Sorry

Answer (score 5):

I created a library call WScrarchView where you can implement scratch view just few lines in layout xml. Hope this can help those who are still looking for the similar solution https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView

of course you are welcome to copy the codes and customize based on your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution would be two layers on top of each other (easily achievable with the RelativeLayout) . Bottom layer will contain whatever content needs to be revealed. Top layer is a canvas filled with non-transparent color. As you detect the touch event start tracing the finger and paint fully transparent color replacing old color on the same path. You can find tutorials on [how to paint with the finger here](http://goo.gl/tlr9h)

Comment: what if i use an Bitmap for the top layer? how to reveal the bottom layer per scratch?

Comment: You would still have to paint bitmap on canvas and make pixels fully transparent as you go. I would not try to do it directly using Bitmap object

Answer (score -1):

You can use samsung [S-Pen SDk](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=11284&nacode=uk) for scratching the image its free but it works from **2.3 OS version**